# How to find a property type from javascript object?

Tags: javascript

How can I find out which property of an object is an Array type?
Given the sample code below, I would expect to get the value `OrderItemList`.

```
function Order() {
    this.Id = 0;
    this.LocationID = 0;
    this.OrderItemList = new Array();      
}

var orderObject = new Order();
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to do? What do you mean by "associated array list"?

Comment: `orderObject.OrderItemList`?

Comment: @ChrisHayes there is an option in breezejs to get navigation property such as objectType.navigationProperties; . May be Mr. Amin Uddin needs this type of option in angularjs or jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you have an Object in javascript and you want to know if it contains an Array or not. If that's what you want to achieve you can simply traverse through all the `keys` for that object and check if the value is an `instanceOf` array.

In Jquery, you could do something like this ([updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zx876pxr/2/)):

```
$.each( orderObject, function( key, value ) {
if(value instanceof Array){
   console.log(key);
  }
});
```

Javascript equivalent:

```
for (var key in orderObject) {
 var val = orderObject[key];
  if (val instanceof Array){
   console.log(key);    
  }
}
```

I hope it gets you started in the right direction.

**Edit** - Like many have already pointed `length` attribute can **not** be used to uniquely distinguish an array from a string although you could do a `typeof` check to see if the value is a string.

Comment: `value.length` will also show the number of character of a string.

Comment: Not to mention you can easily have an object with a key of `length`, and that object can be a property of the original object.

Comment: @Vivek Pradhan, I need to collect all array type property of an object.

Comment: @AminUddin It's still not clear what that means. Please edit your question with at least some sample input/output.

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi, I stand corrected. Please see the updated answer and I have revised the jsfiddle as well to include other test cases like others have mentioned.

Comment: I want to avoid jQuery. i.e I need to avoid $.each

Comment: I have added a javascript alternative to the answer already. You could use that.